# Creating dynamic menu in C# with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm wondering if something like this could be done -

I have a menuItem called "Portfolios", and within it two sub MenuItems "Load Portfolios" and "View Portfolios". When you click Load Portfolios, it will prompt to open a file containing the portfolio names, then I want the View Portfolios to add these names as sub MenuItems, something like this ->

```
Portfolios:
   Load Portfolios
       View Portfolios:
           Portfolio1
           Portfolio2
           Portfolio3
```

I honestly have no idea how to go about this, and I haven't come across any tutorials that could help so any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little broad so I'll summarize what you need to do:

- Follow the MVVM pattern
- In the "main" ViewModel, make an `ObservableCollection<Portfolio>` named SubMenuItems
- In your view (XAML), start with this and build over it:

  ```
  <Menu>
      <MenuItem Header="Main Menu" ItemsSource="{Binding SubMenuItems}" />
  </Menu>
  ```

  .

Answer (score -1):

It's straightforward:

```
// Create MenuItem
MenuItem mnuFile = new MenuItem();
mnuFile.Name = "mnuFile"; // The x:Name
mnuFile.Header = "_File";

// Add to mnuMain's Items
mnuMain.Items.Add(mnuFile);
```

Comment: Yeah I actually figured it out, turns out I was suppose to use ItemsSource to bind the MenuItem to an observablecollection, thanks anyways :) !

Comment: -1. instancing or referencing UI Elements in code is a bad practice, detrimental for scalability and generates unneeded tight coupling between c# code and UIElements that should be defined in XAML instead.